# Important hyperparameters in survival random forest that need optimizing?

Tags: machine-learning, survival, random-forest, tuning

I use survival random forest for a relatively large dataset with 1200 obs and 40 features. I also wanted to compare 3 algorithms with each other by benchmarking.
As tuning can be computationally expensive.

1. What are Important hyperparameters for survival random forest algorithms?
2. Is it allowed that we select just a limited subset of hyperparameters (e.g.. `mtry` and `nodesize`) and not all or many to tune?
3. How to better identify the important parameters and those that contribute to the improvement of the model?